Customizable Vertical Rule / Divider Like `\vrule` With Automatic Height
I need to create a customizable vertical rule (divider) that behaves like \vrule regarding height calculation within different environments, such as minipages, mdframes, arrays, and tcolorbox boxes.

For example, here is a tcolorbox case where I used two minipages to split the space inside the box.

I want this rule to be customizable in color, width, and line end types. Instead of using \vrule, which might not offer the customization, I attempted to use TikZ to define a custom command (e.g. \myvrule) to achieve this.
%=======      TikZ Custom Vrule      ========% 
%=======                             ========%
\newcommand{\myvrule}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]%
    \draw[#1] (frame.south) -- (frame.north);


However, I encountered an issue where the line did not adjust to the height of the box correctly. Unlike \vrule, My current attempt does not seem to adapt to changes in the height of the current bounding box -in this case tcbox-.

Example of using \vrule


Example of using \myvrule


Below is a minimal working example (MWE) with a tcolorbox to illustrate my problem:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.misc,fadings,fit}


%=======      TikZ Custom Vrule      ========% 
%=======                             ========%
\newcommand{\myvrule}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]%
    \draw[#1] (frame.south) -- (frame.north);
}

%=======      TCB GenBox (Generic Box) Env      ========% 
%=======                                        ========%
\NewDocumentEnvironment{genbox}{m O{red}}{%
    \begin{genboxenv}{#1}{#2}
    }%
    {%
    \end{genboxenv}
}%
\newtcolorbox{genboxenv}[2]%
{   coltitle=black,%
    detach title,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,%
    enhanced,%
    blanker,
    boxsep=15pt,
    top=15pt,
    title={#1},
    %
    %-------    GenBox Overlay     -------%
    %-------                       -------%
    overlay={
        \node[coordinate] (nw) at (interior.north west){};
        \node[coordinate] (ne) at (interior.north east){};
        \node[coordinate] (se) at (interior.south east){};
        \node[coordinate] (sw) at (interior.south west){};
        
        \path[%
        very thick,
        draw=#2!40,
        rounded corners=3pt,
        left color = white,
        right color = #2!40%
        ] (nw) -- (ne) -- (se) -- (sw) -- cycle;
        
        \node[%
        draw= #2!40,
        very thick,
        rounded corners=3pt,
        text height=10pt,
        anchor=north west,%
        ] (titlebox) at (nw){\tcbtitle};
    }                 
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{genbox}{Some Title}{}
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            This is some random text before the math:
            \lipsum[1][1-3] For
            \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \[ x=1, y=-1 \]
            Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)
        \end{minipage}
        %%
        \hfill
        \vrule
        \hfill
        %%
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            This is some random text before the math:
            \lipsum[1][1-3] For
            \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \[ x=1, y=-1 \]
            Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)
        \end{minipage}
    \end{genbox}
    
    
    
    \begin{genbox}{Some Title}{}
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            This is some random text before the math:
            \lipsum[1][1-2] For
            \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \[ x=1, y=-1 \]
            Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)
        \end{minipage}
        %%
        \hfill
        \myvrule{|-|,color=red!60, line width=2pt}
        \hfill
        %%
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            This is some random text before the math:
            \lipsum[1][1-2] For
            \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \( x=1, y=-1 \)
            Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)
        \end{minipage}
    \end{genbox}
        
\end{document}


I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or alternative approaches to hopefully create a universal custom vertical rule that dynamically adapts to the height of the bounding box of the current environment, not exclusive to the tcolorbox case if possible. Thank you for your time and expertise.

Answer to revised question
To do this in arbitrary contexts, you need to have a self-sufficient way of measuring the height and depth of the content on each side of the rule. The most straightforward way to do this (the only way?) is to box the content of each side, measure the total height and depth of each, keep the maximum of these two and draw the rule accordingly. Then you need to spit the lot out again into the stream of content being typeset.
Coffins provide a higher-level interface to boxes and are easier to manage. In particular, they offer more intuitive alignment options. There is a package xcoffins, which I like, but the expl3 programming layer is somewhat easier to use.
Strategy:

put the left side in a coffin & measure height + depth;
do the same for the right;
compare & save the largest of the two dimensions;
increase this dimension by a user-definable dimension so the rule is not too tight-fitting;
join the two coffins, aligning them on their vertical centres and offsetting the right by a user-definable separation;
reuse the second coffin and put a tikz macro inside to draw the vertical rule with whatever bells & whistles have been requested;
join the first coffin to the second, aligning them on their vertical centres and aligning the horizontal centre of the rule with the right edge of the content on the left;
typeset the coffin, optionally with a frame to show the bounding box (slightly alters positioning - intended only for debugging).

The syntax is
\mvrule[<key-value list>]{<content for left>}{<content for right>}

where various keys are available:

mvrule style={<list of pgf/tikz key-value options>};
sep={<dimension>} separation between left and right content;
lhs wd ={<dimension>} width for left side;
rhs wd ={<dimension>} width for right side;
add to total height={<dimension>} margin to increase rule's height by (will be divided equally between top and bottom);
lhs xpole, lhs ypole, rhs xpole, rhs ypole, rule xpole and rule ypole set the horizontal and vertical poles used for alignment for the left hand content, the right hand content and the rule1;
show bb=true|false put in an \fbox for debugging purposes only.


Note that some packages are added just to help with bad boxes. A wider page helps (geometry), but you really need hyphenation (babel for latin) as Latin doesn't really work with US English hyphenation patterns2.
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722721/ addaswyd o gwestiwn aglobalphenomenon: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/722717/
\documentclass[latin]{article}
\usepackage[hscale=.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\NewTColorBox{Genbox}{ O{} m O{red} }{%
  coltitle=black,
  detach title,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  enhanced,
  blank,
  boxsep=15pt,
  top=15pt,
  title={#2},
  overlay={%
    \node[coordinate] (nw) at (interior.north west){};
    \node[coordinate] (ne) at (interior.north east){};
    \node[coordinate] (se) at (interior.south east){};
    \node[coordinate] (sw) at (interior.south west){};
    \path[%
    very thick,
    draw=#3!40,
    rounded corners=3pt,
    left color = white,
    right color = #3!40%
    ] (nw) -- (ne) -- (se) -- (sw) -- cycle;
    \node[%
    draw= #3!40,
    very thick,
    rounded corners=3pt,
    text height=10pt,
    anchor=north west,%
    ] (titlebox) at (nw){\tcbtitle};
  },  
  #1,  
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_coffin
\dim_new:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_ht_dim
\tl_new:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_tmpb_tl
\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument / end } { mvrule }
{
  \keys_define:nn { aglobalphenomenon }
  {
    mvrule ~ style .tl_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_style_tl,
    mvrule ~ style .initial:n = { |-|, red!60, line ~ width = 2pt },
    add ~ to ~ total ~ height .dim_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_rule_ht_dim,
    add ~ to ~ total ~ height .initial:n = 2.5em,
    lhs ~ wd .dim_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_dim,
    lhs ~ wd .initial:n = { .425\linewidth },
    rhs ~ wd .dim_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_dim,
    rhs ~ wd .initial:n = { .425\linewidth },
    sep .dim_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_sep_dim,
    sep .initial:n = { 0.05\linewidth },
    show ~ bb .bool_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_bb_bool,
    show ~ bb .initial:n = false,
    show ~ bb .default:n = true,
    lhs ~ xpole .tl_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_xpole_tl,
    lhs ~ ypole .tl_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_ypole_tl,
    rhs ~ xpole .tl_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_xpole_tl,
    rhs ~ ypole .tl_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_ypole_tl,
    lhs ~ xpole .initial:n = {r},
    lhs ~ ypole .initial:n = {vc},
    rhs ~ xpole .initial:n = {l},
    rhs ~ ypole .initial:n = {vc},
    rule ~ xpole .tl_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_rule_xpole_tl,
    rule ~ ypole .tl_set:N = \l_aglobalphenomenon_rule_ypole_tl,
    rule ~ xpole .initial:n = {hc},
    rule ~ ypole .initial:n = {vc},
  }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \mvrule { o +m +m }
{
  \group_begin:
  \IfValueT { #1 } 
  {
    \keys_set:nn { aglobalphenomenon } { #1 }
  }
  \aglobalphenomenon_mvrule:Vnn \l_aglobalphenomenon_style_tl { #2 } { #3 }
  \group_end:
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \aglobalphenomenon_mvrule:nnn #1#2#3
{
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin { \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_dim } { #2 }
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_coffin { \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_dim } { #3 }
  \dim_compare:nNnTF { \coffin_ht:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin + \coffin_dp:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin  } > { \coffin_ht:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_coffin  + \coffin_dp:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_coffin }
  {
    \dim_set:Nn \l_aglobalphenomenon_ht_dim { \coffin_ht:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin + \coffin_dp:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin  }
  }
  {
    \dim_set:Nn \l_aglobalphenomenon_ht_dim { \coffin_ht:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_coffin  + \coffin_dp:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_coffin  }
  }
  \dim_add:Nn \l_aglobalphenomenon_ht_dim { \l_aglobalphenomenon_sep_dim }
  \coffin_join:NVVNVVnn 
  \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_xpole_tl \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_ypole_tl 
  \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_coffin \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_xpole_tl \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_ypole_tl 
  { \l_aglobalphenomenon_sep_dim } {0pt}
  \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_coffin 
  {
    \tikz{
      \draw [#1] (0,0) -- ++(0pt,\l_aglobalphenomenon_ht_dim);
    }
  }
  \tl_set:Ne \l_aglobalphenomenon_tmpa_tl { \exp_not:N \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin - \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_xpole_tl }
  \tl_set:Ne \l_aglobalphenomenon_tmpb_tl { \exp_not:N  \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin - \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_ypole_tl }
  \coffin_join:NVVNVVnn 
  \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin \l_aglobalphenomenon_tmpa_tl \l_aglobalphenomenon_tmpb_tl  
  \l_aglobalphenomenon_rhs_coffin \l_aglobalphenomenon_rule_xpole_tl \l_aglobalphenomenon_rule_ypole_tl
  {.5\l_aglobalphenomenon_sep_dim}{0pt}
  \bool_if:NTF \l_aglobalphenomenon_bb_bool
  {% note that this will alter the position very slightly due to the width of the line drawn for the fbox
    \fbox{\coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin {b}{l}{0pt}{0pt}}
  }{
    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_aglobalphenomenon_lhs_coffin {b}{l}{0pt}{0pt}
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \aglobalphenomenon_mvrule:nnn { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn { N VV N VV nn }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{Genbox}{Some Title}\noindent
  \mvrule{%
    This is some random text before the math:
    \lipsum[1][1-2] For
    \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \[ x=1, y=-1 \]
    Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)}
  {%
    This is some random text before the math:
    \lipsum[1][1-2] For
    \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \( x=1, y=-1 \)
    Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)}
\end{Genbox}

\mvrule[mvrule style={double=gray!50, draw=gray, Circle-Circle}]{%
  This is some random text before the math:
  \lipsum[1][1-2] For
  \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \[ x=1, y=-1 \]
  Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)}
{%
  This is some random text before the math:
  \lipsum[1][1-2] For
  \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \( x=1, y=-1 \)
  Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)}

\mvrule[mvrule style={double=gray!50, draw=gray, Circle-Circle},lhs wd=.35\linewidth,rhs wd=.5\linewidth]{%
  This is some random text before the math:
  \lipsum[1][1-2] For
  \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \[ x=1, y=-1 \]
  Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)}
{%
  This is some random text before the math:
  \lipsum[1][1-2] For
  \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \( x=1, y=-1 \)
  Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)}

\NewDocumentCommand \testme {m} {%
  \mvrule[mvrule style={double=gray!50, draw=gray, Circle-Circle},lhs wd=.35\linewidth,rhs wd=.5\linewidth,#1]{%
    This is some random text before the math:
    \lipsum[1][1-2] For
    \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \[ x=1, y=-1 \]
    Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)}
  {%
    This is some random text before the math:
    \lipsum[1][1-2] For
    \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \( x=1, y=-1 \)
    Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)}%
}%
\testme{}

\testme{lhs xpole=r,lhs ypole=b,rhs xpole=l,rhs ypole=t,rule xpole=hc,rule ypole=B}

\testme{lhs ypole=B,rhs ypole=vc,rule ypole=T}

\testme{lhs ypole=T,rule ypole=vc,rhs ypole=B}
\pagestyle{empty}
\end{document}

1 Actually the poles for the left-hand content are used twice: to align with the right-hand content and to align with the vertical rule. These could be distinguished, if desired, but configuration using key-values gets tricky at this point because the names of poles now require expl3 syntax to be enabled, which would make a mess. This could be worked around, but I'm not convinced the additional flexibility would actually be useful. I'm not even sure configuring the poles for the rule is useful, but that comes cheap, so why not?
2 This is one reason I prefer kantlipsum for examples, though not the main one.
Answer to original question
The problem is not just that (frame.north) and (frame.south) are points on the border of your box, but that because the rule then exceeds the height of the content of the box, the box grows to accommodate it. Moreover, the use of arrow tips further complicates this - for a thick line, the additional dimensions are significant.
You want to draw the rule without affecting the size of the box. You could do this with tikzmark, say, or calculation and then use overlay or similar to stop the rule occupying actual space, but why reinvent the wheel when you're already using a shiny high tech version with kaleidoscopic effects, pull-down thing-a-me-bobs and popup whatsits?
Rather than using blanker, use at most blank. (But you could simplify your code further by not re-implementing the central hub of this wheel.) Use sidebyside rather than minipages. Ideally, this would let you just use segmentation style, but your tikz code overwrites the line, even if I put it into underlay, so rather than trying to undo that, too, I figured I would just add it to overlay.
You don't need two environment definitions. Just use \NewTColorBox which is a wrapper around \NewDocumentEnvironment. I added an initial optional argument to take configuration options and made mvrule a style for the rule.
This way the code stays flexible and most of the mark up is in the preamble rather than the boxes.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.misc,fadings,fit}
\tcbset{%
  /tcb/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},
  /tikz/mvrule aux/.style={draw,solid},
  mvrule/.code={%
    \pgfqkeys{/tikz}{mvrule aux/.style={#1}}%
  },
}
\NewTColorBox{genbox}{ O{} m O{red} }{%
  coltitle=black,
  detach title,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  enhanced,
  blank,
  boxsep=15pt,
  top=15pt,
  title={#2},
  sidebyside,
  lefthand width=.4\textwidth,righthand width=.4\textwidth,
  overlay={%
    \node[coordinate] (nw) at (interior.north west){};
    \node[coordinate] (ne) at (interior.north east){};
    \node[coordinate] (se) at (interior.south east){};
    \node[coordinate] (sw) at (interior.south west){};
    \path[%
      very thick,
      draw=#3!40,
      rounded corners=3pt,
      left color = white,
      right color = #3!40%
    ] (nw) -- (ne) -- (se) -- (sw) -- cycle;
    \node[%
      draw= #3!40,
      very thick,
      rounded corners=3pt,
      text height=10pt,
      anchor=north west,%
    ] (titlebox) at (nw){\tcbtitle};
    \draw [mvrule aux] ([yshift=-0pt]interior.north |- titlebox.south) -- ([yshift=15pt]interior.south);
  },  
  #1,  
}
\begin{document}
\begin{genbox}{Some Title}
  This is some random text before the math:
  \lipsum[1][1-3] For
  \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \[ x=1, y=-1 \]
  Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)
  \tcblower
  This is some random text before the math:
  \lipsum[1][1-3] For
  \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \[ x=1, y=-1 \]
  Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)
\end{genbox}

\begin{genbox}[mvrule={line width=2pt,red!60,|-|}]{Some Title}
  This is some random text before the math:
  \lipsum[1][1-2] For
  \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \[ x=1, y=-1 \]
  Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)
  \tcblower
  This is some random text before the math:
  \lipsum[1][1-2] For
  \( A(1,-1) \) we have: \( x=1, y=-1 \)
  Thus, \( A(r, \theta) = (\sqrt{2}, \tfrac{7}{4} \pi) \)
\end{genbox}
\end{document}


Thank you so so much for this comprehensive and definitive solution! and for the effort of basically creating an entirely new sophisticated system.
I didn't know of coffins before your contribution. Can this system have vertical alignments like (t for top, b for bottom, etc. as in minipage) for when the height difference is noticeably big?
Whether they can or not, thank you again for your patience, diligence and expertise.

@aglobalphenomenon We should clear up a little so the mods don't have to tidy up after us ;). I could add options for the poles if you want them.

I'd be grateful if you could add options for the poles, if it is not too much to ask. And I will be learning about coffins and their uses thanks to you.

@aglobalphenomenon Please see edit. Slight fiddling with expansion required, but not much because this is expl3.

Thanks a lot with my deepest gratitude and best wishes. Kept you busy with this one. ^_^;
